# Insert the number in the array

Tags: c++

This is the main code:

```
int main(){
    unsigned d=0, x, a[100]={0};
    cout << "Input the value of x: ";
    cin>>x;
    caricaArray(a,x,d);
        for(unsigned i=0 ; i<d ;i++)
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I need to make a function the inserts in the array all the number between 0 to 100 that are divisible by the integer x.

I tried with my code:

```
void caricaArray(unsigned a[], unsigned x, unsigned d){
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++ )   
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ){
            if( i % x == 0 ){
                d++; 
                a[j] == i;
            }
        }
}
```

Is there anyone here has another insight?
thank youu

Comment: Well, for one thing it seems that `a[j]` should have been `a[d-1]`.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: What is your question? Is the code not working? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: For a second thing, you pass `d` *by value* so, any changes you make to that inside the function will have no effect on the value in `main`.

Comment: Yeah, the code is not working. the number isnt inserted into the array a..

Comment: Note that in C++ there is a much nicer way of working with resizable arrays. I see you use d to count the number of divisible numbers. But with std::vector you can just add (push_back) a found value to a vector. Also vectors are much less likely to give you memory problems. Example here : https://godbolt.org/z/6jrW3EKsq

Comment: If you move the contents of your function into `main`, you could reduce the need for an array.

Comment: *"Is there anyone here has another insight?"* -- my insight is that your code has multiple issues, and since we don't know which symptom you are looking at, we don't know which issue to address. Please add a description of why you believe your code is not correct, something more precise than "not working". For a simple input, what is that input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? *Bonus:* Can you simplify your code to focus on one specific malfunction? Don't worry about your assigned task; focus on the malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you are storing multiples of `x` into the array, between `x` and 100.

```
unsigned int index = 0U;
for (unsigned int i = x; i < 100; i = i + x)
{
    a[index++] = i;  
}
```

A number that is evenly divisible by `x` is a multiple of `x`.

**Edit 1:  Division.**
If you don't like multiplication, you could use division.

```
unsigned int array_index = 0U;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
{
  if ((i % x) == 0)
  {
      a[array_index++] = i;
  }
}
```

In both of the above examples, you can replace the array assignment by printing the value.

Comment: Yeah it works, but i used the d instead of index. I put them in the main. thank you! But, I still can make it as a function. The main task here is to make a function. Is there any other insight for me?

Comment: Put the contents into a function, then figure out what parameters you need to pass.  One of the concepts I'm showing is that you only need one loop, not two.

Comment: Okay, Noted. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the insight! now the code is work. I just forget to put pointer on d as parameter of the function.